# Is there a way to calculate a cumulative sum in Pandas that is reset after a condition / threshold is met?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, numpy, shift, cumsum

I have a specific use case where I need to calculate a running total that is reset/adjusted every time it exceeds another running total in the same dataframe.   The running total needs to be reduced by the amount it exceed the running total of that other column.

This can be relatively easily achieved in Excel, but really struggling how perform this in Pandas or Numpy.

In below example you can see my desired result.

[image: Excel Example Desired Result]

You can see how columns "E" and "F" are derived in formulas below.

[image: Excel Example Formulas]

This is the dataframe in Pandas. I did try to create a lambda function as well as use the pandas.DataFrame.shift method but without success.

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'date': ['2023-01-01', '2023-01-02', '2023-01-03', '2023-01-04','2023-01-05','2023-01-06'],
        'a': [10, 10, 15, 15,15,15],
       'b': [0,5,60,5,0,80]
       }
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)

df['a rt'] = df['a'].cumsum()
df['b rt'] = df['b'].cumsum()
```

I would also like to be able to apply this custom function separately to each "product" and "location" combination in the same dataframe.  Please see sample input below:

| product | location | date | a | b |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | loc1 | 2023-1-1 | 10 | 0 |
| A | loc1 | 2023-1-2 | 10 | 5 |
| A | loc1 | 2023-1-3 | 15 | 60 |
| A | loc1 | 2023-1-4 | 15 | 0 |
| A | loc1 | 2023-1-5 | 15 | 0 |
| A | loc1 | 2023-1-6 | 15 | 80 |
| B | loc1 | 2023-1-1 | 5 | 0 |
| B | loc1 | 2023-1-2 | 5 | 0 |
| B | loc1 | 2023-1-3 | 5 | 0 |
| B | loc1 | 2023-1-4 | 4 | 10 |
| B | loc1 | 2023-1-5 | 4 | 0 |
| B | loc1 | 2023-1-6 | 3 | 0 |
| B | loc2 | 2023-1-1 | 25 | 0 |
| B | loc2 | 2023-1-2 | 25 | 5 |
| B | loc2 | 2023-1-3 | 25 | 50 |
| B | loc2 | 2023-1-4 | 10 | 0 |
| B | loc2 | 2023-1-5 | 5 | 70 |
| B | loc2 | 2023-1-6 | 4 | 0 |
| C | loc2 | 2023-1-1 | 8 | 0 |
| C | loc2 | 2023-1-2 | 8 | 5 |
| C | loc2 | 2023-1-3 | 8 | 22 |
| C | loc2 | 2023-1-4 | 8 | 2 |
| C | loc2 | 2023-1-5 | 8 | 10 |
| C | loc2 | 2023-1-6 | 8 | 20 |

I would to see if possible to get the following output:

| product | location | date | a | b | a rt | b rt adj. | delta |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | loc1 | 2023-1-1 | 10 | 0 | 10 | 0 | 0 |
| A | loc1 | 2023-1-2 | 10 | 5 | 20 | 5 | 0 |
| A | loc1 | 2023-1-3 | 15 | 60 | 35 | 65 | 30 |
| A | loc1 | 2023-1-4 | 15 | 0 | 50 | 35 | 0 |
| A | loc1 | 2023-1-5 | 15 | 0 | 65 | 35 | 0 |
| A | loc1 | 2023-1-6 | 15 | 80 | 80 | 115 | 35 |
| B | loc1 | 2023-1-1 | 5 | 0 | 5 | 0 | 0 |
| B | loc1 | 2023-1-2 | 5 | 0 | 10 | 0 | 0 |
| B | loc1 | 2023-1-3 | 5 | 0 | 15 | 0 | 0 |
| B | loc1 | 2023-1-4 | 4 | 10 | 19 | 10 | 0 |
| B | loc1 | 2023-1-5 | 4 | 0 | 23 | 10 | 0 |
| B | loc1 | 2023-1-6 | 3 | 0 | 26 | 10 | 0 |
| B | loc2 | 2023-1-1 | 25 | 0 | 25 | 0 | 0 |
| B | loc2 | 2023-1-2 | 25 | 5 | 50 | 5 | 0 |
| B | loc2 | 2023-1-3 | 25 | 50 | 75 | 55 | 0 |
| B | loc2 | 2023-1-4 | 10 | 0 | 85 | 55 | 0 |
| B | loc2 | 2023-1-5 | 5 | 70 | 90 | 125 | 35 |
| B | loc2 | 2023-1-6 | 4 | 0 | 94 | 90 | 0 |
| C | loc2 | 2023-1-1 | 8 | 0 | 8 | 0 | 0 |
| C | loc2 | 2023-1-2 | 8 | 5 | 16 | 5 | 0 |
| C | loc2 | 2023-1-3 | 8 | 22 | 24 | 27 | 3 |
| C | loc2 | 2023-1-4 | 8 | 2 | 32 | 26 | 0 |
| C | loc2 | 2023-1-5 | 8 | 10 | 40 | 36 | 0 |
| C | loc2 | 2023-1-6 | 8 | 20 | 48 | 56 | 8 |

Answer (score 1):

This won't be easy to vectorize, because you have values that depends on previous computed values.

You can however make custom function/generator that computes these column values:

```py
def get_D_E_F(B, C):
    B, C = iter(B), iter(C)
    prev_d, prev_e = next(B), next(C)
    prev_f = prev_e - prev_d if prev_e > prev_d else 0
    yield prev_d, prev_e, prev_f

    while True:
        try:
            current_d = next(B) + prev_d
            current_e = next(C) + prev_e - prev_f
            current_f = current_e - current_d if current_e > current_d else 0
            yield current_d, current_e, current_f
            prev_d, prev_e, prev_f = current_d, current_e, current_f
        except StopIteration:
            break

df[['a rt', 'b rt adj.', 'delta']] = list(get_D_E_F(df['a'], df['b']))
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
         date   a   b  a rt  b rt adj.  delta
0  2023-01-01  10   0    10          0      0
1  2023-01-02  10   5    20          5      0
2  2023-01-03  15  60    35         65     30
3  2023-01-04  15   0    50         35      0
4  2023-01-05  15   0    65         35      0
5  2023-01-06  15  80    80        115     35
```

---

EDIT: With updated dataframe you can do:

```py
out = (
    df.groupby(["product", "location"])
    .apply(
        lambda x: pd.concat(
            [
                x["date"].reset_index(drop=True),
                pd.DataFrame(
                    get_D_E_F(x["a"], x["b"]), columns=["a rt", "b rt adj.", "delta"]
                ),
            ],
            axis=1,
        )
    )
    .droplevel(2)
    .reset_index()
)
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
   product location      date  a rt  b rt adj.  delta
0        A     loc1  2023-1-1    10          0      0
1        A     loc1  2023-1-2    20          5      0
2        A     loc1  2023-1-3    35         65     30
3        A     loc1  2023-1-4    50         35      0
4        A     loc1  2023-1-5    65         35      0
5        A     loc1  2023-1-6    80        115     35
6        B     loc1  2023-1-1     5          0      0
7        B     loc1  2023-1-2    10          0      0
8        B     loc1  2023-1-3    15          0      0
9        B     loc1  2023-1-4    19         10      0
10       B     loc1  2023-1-5    23         10      0
11       B     loc1  2023-1-6    26         10      0
12       B     loc2  2023-1-1    25          0      0
13       B     loc2  2023-1-2    50          5      0
14       B     loc2  2023-1-3    75         55      0
15       B     loc2  2023-1-4    85         55      0
16       B     loc2  2023-1-5    90        125     35
17       B     loc2  2023-1-6    94         90      0
18       C     loc2  2023-1-1     8          0      0
19       C     loc2  2023-1-2    16          5      0
20       C     loc2  2023-1-3    24         27      3
21       C     loc2  2023-1-4    32         26      0
22       C     loc2  2023-1-5    40         36      0
23       C     loc2  2023-1-6    48         56      8
```

Comment: Hi Andrej, thank you so much for the extremely quick response.   This works perfectly.   As a follow question my dataset I am trying to apply this to is actually much larger.   I have additional columns (groups) as an example Location and Product that I need to apply this funtion to.   As an example I would use df.groupby(['Location','Product'])['a'].cumsum()  how could i do something similar using your function?

Comment: To give mo background tried `df[['a rt', 'b rt adj.', 'delta']] = list(get_D_E_F(df.groupby(['product','location'])['a'], df.groupby(['product','location'])['b']))` but get the following error: ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Comment: @Jan Maybe you can edit your question and put sample input and output there (as text, so we can copy-and-paste it)

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. I have added the sample to the bottom of the original question.

Answer (score 0):

Lets define a custom function to replicate the behaviour of excel formula. Also you can optionally use `numba` to compile the function in order to achieve `C` like speeds

```
from numba import njit

@njit
def func(A, B):
    a_cs, b_cs, delta = 0, 0, 0
    for a, b in zip(A, B):
        a_cs += a
        b_cs += b

        cond = b_cs > a_cs
        if cond:
            delta = b_cs - a_cs

        yield (a_cs, b_cs, delta)
        if cond:
            b_cs = a_cs # reset
        
        delta = 0


df[['a_rt', 'b_rt', 'delta']] = [*func(df.a.values, df.b.values)]
```

Result

```
         date   a   b  a_rt  b_rt  delta
0  2023-01-01  10   0    10     0      0
1  2023-01-02  10   5    20     5      0
2  2023-01-03  15  60    35    65     30
3  2023-01-04  15   0    50    35      0
4  2023-01-05  15   0    65    35      0
5  2023-01-06  15  80    80   115     35
```